# FindElement when no Id or Name is given in selenium webdriver c#

Tags: c#, selenium, css-selectors

Looking for a way to find an element that is in a div in a custom dropdown menu. I tried a few different things but I can not find a good CssSelector or XPath examples that work for this.

```
<div tabindex="0" class="config-button">
  <ul class="onclick-menu-content">
    <li>
      <a href="/IID/User">User</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/IID/Roles">Roles</a>
    </li>
```

I am managing to get LinkText to work for my Navigation bar now but not for the links in my dropdown (That is in my navbar).

Comment: Where do you exactly want to find? what is your trouble?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read the guide [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), especially the part on Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE). This will help you solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and what the results were so we can better help you.

Comment: I want to find the link that is in my dropdown.

Comment: driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@class='config-button']/ul/li[1]")).Click();
This says that the element is not currently visible.

Answer (score 0):

Make it simple and find it *by link text*:

```
driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("User"));
```

Answer (score 0):

The following apply if you have only one li element within your ul
if you want to find the ul use the css selector ".onclick-menu-content"

for the li -> ".onclick-menu-content li"

for the a -> ".onclick-menu-content a"

if there is no class for the ul you can find the a by using the following
".config-button ul a" or just ".config-button a" as its only one

if you have multiple li elements you need to make your variable a list type

```
List<WebElement>
```

this way you'll get all the elements that apply to the css selector and you can search within each element from the list for child elements